# Getting extension of an image from base64 encoded string -Cakephp

Tags: php

Iam doing APIs of an IOS Application in cakephp.Iam getting base64 encoded string as request parameter.How can i find extension of image(png,jpeg) from that string.

Comment: is that string encoded as a data uri? Because base64 data does not have an "extension". it's just a string. The filename would be embedded in the MIME headers surrounding the b64 string, if any.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to decode the string then you can extract the extension from the string. My code example below should work for you.

```
$filename = base64_decode($encoded);

$extension = substr($filename, strpos($filename, ".") + 1);

echo $extension;
```

Lee

Comment: This is providing you meant the filename is base64 encoded, and not the actual image...